# Mongoose NodeJS Express - How to Push Data To a Specific Sub Document Object Array

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

thank you in advance for any help.

My problem is essentially to add data to a specific sub document.

### I have the following models in my NodeJS server:

### MODELS

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const dataSchema = new Schema({
    time: Date,
    value: String
});

const nodeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    number: Number,
    status: String,
    lastSeen: Date,
    data: [dataSchema]
});

const siteSchema = new Schema({
    code: String,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    totalNodes: Number,
    nodes: [nodeSchema]
});

const Site = mongoose.model('site',siteSchema);
module.exports = Site;
```

### Which basically looks like this:

### Example

```
 {
        "_id": "5fa169473a394829bc485069",
        "code": "xfx3090",
        "name": "Name of this site",
        "description": "Some description",
        "totalNodes": 2,
        "__v": 0,
        "nodes": [
            {
                "_id": "5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2",
                "name": "device name",
                "description": "device description",
                "number": 1,
                "status": "Offline",
                "lastSeen": "2020-11-03T19:27:50.062Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "value": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "Value": "146"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fa1b10f4f24051520f85a58",
                "name": "device name",
                "description": "device description",
                "number": 2,
                "status": "Offline",
                "lastSeen": "2020-11-03T19:35:43.409Z",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "Date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "Value": "555"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see I have created two dummy nodes with some random data.

My question now is, say I want to add some data to Node 1. How will this code look?

I've tried many variations and attempted many different things without any luck. I know this would be easier by using the Object Id's, but I was hoping there is a way around this.

My Best result so far was with this code, but unfortunately it doesn't add any data.

```
addNodeData: async (req,res,next) => {
        const {siteCode} = xfx3090; //req.params
        const { nodeNumber } = 1;  //req. params - just to show example

        const nodeData = await Site.findOneAndUpdate({'code': siteCode, 'node.number': nodeNumber}, {$push: {'data':{'time': Date.now(), 'value':1223}}});

        res.status(200).json({message:'success'});
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the positional operator `$`.

The query you want is something like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "5fa169473a394829bc485069",
  "nodes._id": "5fa1af361e085b516066d7e2"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "nodes.$.data": {
      "Date": "newDate",
      "value": "newValue"
    }
  }
})
```

The first part is to find the document. I'm assuming `nodes._id` is not unique so I match `_id` too.

Then, with the pointer in the document you want to add the new data, you use `$push` into `nodes.$.data`. So, in the filed `data` there will be a new object.

A mongo plauground example is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPdaTAZdUGH)

Comment: nice solution. I'd add the prototype `update(<filter>, <update>, <options>)`.  Looks like the site's name could be a good filter too.